# MySQL community server not starting in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql

Whenever I run `systemctl status mysql.service` this is the output:

```
    ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-10-07 22:36:27 UTC; 17s ago
    Process: 7996 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

This is the result of `journalctl -xe -u mysql.service`:

```
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, rest
    -- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the res
    -- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
    --
    -- The result is RESULT.
    lines 359-381/381 (END)
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart 
    job, restart counter is at 5.
    -- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
    -- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Oct 07 22:36:27 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
```

Result of `systemctl start mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`

```
    Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    root@ns5002486:~# journalctl -xe
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: 2020-10-11T03:04:30.983966Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. 
    Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /va
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: 2020-10-11T03:04:30.986263Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 mysql-systemd-start[32163]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Oct 11 03:04:30 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
    --
    -- The result is RESULT.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    -- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
    -- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    --
    -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
    --
    -- The result is RESULT.
    Oct 11 03:04:31 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=222.186.31.83  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:32 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.208  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:34 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: Failed password for root from 222.186.31.83 port 35207 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:34 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.208 port 42769 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:36 ns5002486 sshd[32189]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.208  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:36 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: Failed password for root from 222.186.31.83 port 35207 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:36 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.208 port 42769 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:38 ns5002486 sshd[32189]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.208 port 52261 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: Failed password for root from 222.186.31.83 port 35207 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.208 port 42769 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: Received disconnect from 222.186.31.83 port 35207:11:  [preauth]
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 222.186.31.83 port 35207 [preauth]
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32045]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=222.186.31.83  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.208 port 42769:11:  [preauth]
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 218.92.0.208 port 42769 [preauth]
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32134]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.208  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:39 ns5002486 sshd[32191]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.208  user=root
    Oct 11 03:04:40 ns5002486 sshd[32189]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.208 port 52261 ssh2
    Oct 11 03:04:41 ns5002486 sshd[32193]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=222.186.31.83  user=root
    lines 1304-1365/1365 (END)
```

Comment: Could you also post the result of `journalctl -xe`?  This problem is relatively frequent as shows a query on this site or on related sites.

Comment: Just added the results of `journalctl -xe`

Comment: Hum, that is too much and too distant from mysqlservice.  Try to reduce to that service: `journalctl -xe -u mysql.service`

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: OK, we are nearing some clarification. Please restart mysql ( systemctl start mysql.service) and post the output + output of journalctl). Please try to copy/paste complete lines. Some info is missing from your copy.

Comment: Updated with new information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem clearly stated (I copied the relevant parts):

```
mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
[ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. 
Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /va
Aborting
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
```

It has well known solutions, as the one I am coying from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/981403/failed-to-start-mysql-community-server):

To resolve it, first check the user that your `mysqld` is attempting to run as; this will be the user "mysql" in a default Debian install (I assume it should be the same for Ubuntu); to verify this, check `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and look for a "user = xxx" line.

Once you know what user mysqld is trying to run as, check that the directory `/var/lib/mysql-files` exists (`sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files` if it doesn't) and is owned by the user `mysqld` runs as (`sudo chown mysql /var/lib/mysql-files` if it isn't; replace "mysql" in the chown command with the correct user name if you're configured to run as a different user).

Then try `sudo mysqld` again and you should either get a successful mysqld startup, or (if there are other problems with your setup) a new and different error message.